# How to use variable with laravel blade `@if`?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to pass a `$path` variable to such Blade expression:

```
@if(Request::url() === 'http://project2.test/{{$path}}')
```

Or

```
@if (Request::path() == '/{{$path}}')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use simple PHP concatenation

```
@if(Request::url() === 'http://project2.test/'.$path )
```

and

```
@if (Request::path() == '/' . $path )
```